# redirecting a html form using response.write in kentico not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, http-post, kentico

I trying to post a HTML form to another URL, in my test the form is created:

```
<html>
<body onload='document.forms["form1"].submit()'>
<form id='form1' method='POST' action='http://localhost:52035/testpage?'>
<input type='hidden' id='name' value='form1' />
<input type='hidden' name='NEW_ITEM["0"] value='1234-ABC'/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

but doesn't send,

the following is a snippet of the form build / send which is accessed on a button click:

```
protected void btnSubmitRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
var hookUrl = SessionHelper.GetValue("hookurl").ToString();
string formId = "form1";
StringBuilder htmlForm = new StringBuilder();
htmlForm.AppendLine("<html>");
htmlForm.AppendLine(String.Format("<body onload='document.forms[\"{0}\"].submit()'>", formId));
htmlForm.AppendLine(String.Format("<form id='{0}' method='POST' action='{1}'>", formId, hookUrl));
htmlForm.AppendLine("<input type='hidden' id='name' value='form1' />");
// test values 
prod.ProductCode = "1234-ABC"
int i = 0;

htmlForm.AppendLine(String.Format("<input type='hidden' name='NEW_ITEM[\"{0}\"] value='{1}'/>",i, prod.ProductCode));
htmlForm.AppendLine("</form>");
                        htmlForm.AppendLine("</body>");
                        htmlForm.AppendLine("</html>");

HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(htmlForm.ToString());
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

}
```

Comment: Your form doesn't have a `name="form1"`.

Comment: Oh, and that should get executed after the `<form>` is loaded.

Comment: Hi Paveen, I added name='form1' and are you saying the htmlForm Line "<body onload ...... >" needs to be changed ?

Comment: No buddy, `onload`, the `<form>` is not seen.

Comment: after adding name='form1', still not working.

Comment: See my above comment. You have to execute it after the document is ready. You need either an event handler or you need a `<script>` tag after the `<form>`.

Comment: I've tried adding  Response.Write("<script>");
                           Response.Write("document.form1.submit()");
                           Response.Write("</script>");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106593/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-johnl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to mention my code was in an ascx page, i moved my code to an aspx page and the response.write now sends the form data to the external URL.

Comment: Solved. I now send the data to aspx code behind page then build the form and post from there.

Answer (score 0):

- There is already plenty of this question if you just search for them
- you have miss end quote on NEW_ITEM...
- And 3th use Ajax + FormData instead of messing with html.

Here is a possible solution to your problem

```html
<body>
  <form id='form1' name='form1' method='POST' action='http://localhost'>
    <input type='text' id='name' value='form1'>
    <input type='text' name='NEW_ITEM["0"]' value='1234-ABC'>
  </form> 
  <script>document.forms.form1.submit()</script>
</body>
```